# How can I trace for a link posted in Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to search for Facebook posts that has a link in their texts.

E.g.: I want to find all public posts which contains the following link: http://www.nytimes.com/video/world/asia/100000002485983/the-making-of-malala.html

How is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Public Post search is no longer available.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0

In other words, it is not possible.

Comment: Do you know any other tool with which I can achieve a similar result (via scraping or the like)?
I would like to do the same for different social media: Twitter, YouTube, Wordpress.

Comment: scraping is not allowed on facebook, but what you want to achieve would not even be possible with scraping. posts of users who did not specifically authorize your app are none of your business, even if they are public. about other platforms, you need to check out their docs.